# JSON response using express

Tags: node.js, express

### I have a working code from Express that returns JSON response from the server to client

Here

- when i use `http:://myserverip/` I get a JSON from Table1
- when i use `Http:://myserverip/table2` I get a JSON from Table2

***So as i understand i need to make 2 separate requests to get JSON from two separate tables
But is there a way to get data from both the tables at a time in one JSON response***

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'DB'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1', function(err, rows, fields)

    {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );


app.get('/table2',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table2', function(err, rows, fields)

    {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Hello, Do you want to append results of two table in single request?

Comment: You could do this, do query for table2 inside callback of table1 and use response.json({table1:table1rowJSON, table2: table2rowJSON});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Instead of nested callbacks as askkirati suggested.

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'DB'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7002);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
    var first, second;

    async.series( [

        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1', function(err, rows, fields)

                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                        first = JSON.stringify(rows);

                        callback();
                });
        },

        // Get the second table contents
        function ( callback ) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM table2', function(err, rows, fields)

            {
                    console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                    console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    second = JSON.stringify(rows);

                    callback();
            });
        }

    // Send the response
    ], function ( error, results ) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        response.end({
            'first' : first,
            'second' : second
        });
    } );

} );

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: You may want to use `async.parallel`, so the second `SELECT` doesn't have to wait for the first to finish.